# Once form is submit on the same page, its not submitting again using jquery until i refresh page

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I am trying to submit my form on the same page using jquery. When this form is submitted and again i try to submit i am failed. and when i refresh page and submit it works fine. whats the problem?

```
$('#csvFile').change(function(){
    $("#senderInfoForm").submit();
});
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/687367/4908989).

Answer (score 1):

this is the code I use for trigger submit a form in .change()

```
$('#csvFile').on('change',function(){
    $('#senderInfoForm').trigger('submit');
});
```

be sure that #senderInfoForm is your form id  not a submit button id .. and for submit a form

```
$('#senderInfoForm').on('submit',function(){
   // code here
});
```