# PHP Javascript - cannot change selector onclick to Remove preview file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm doing upload multiple files(use `<input type="file" multiple/>`) with preview image file  and can remove the image preview and filedata successfully.

but the problem is, I cannot change the selector for onclick to remove filedata.
(If I change to other selector, it will only remove the preview image  but the filedata still be uploaded to my folder)

The selector for click to remove that work successfully is `.selFile` but when
I want to change selector for onclick to `.selFile2` it will not remove filedata)

these are my focus line of code. (To see my Full code, Please look on bottom)

```
    var html = "<div><img src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" data-file='"+f.name+"' class='selFile' 
title='Click to remove'> <span class='selFile2'>" + f.name + "</span><br clear=\"left\"/></div>";
```

..

I change from

```
$("body").on("click", ".selFile", removeFile);
```

to

```
$("body").on("click", ".selFile2", removeFile);
```

but it remove preview image only  not remove filedata (it's still be uploaded to my folder)
..

And I try to change code in `function removeFile(e)`
from `var file = $(this).data("file");` to `var file = $('.selFile).data("file");`   the result is It can remove only 1 filedata. 
...
How could I do?

Here is my full code  (2 pages)

firstpage.html   (I use ajax to post form)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Proper Title</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    #selectedFiles img {
        max-width: 200px;
        max-height: 200px;
        float: left;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>       
    <form id="myForm" method="post"> 
        Multiple Files: <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple><br/>

        <div id="selectedFiles"></div>

        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <script>
    var selDiv = "";
    var storedFiles = [];

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#files").on("change", handleFileSelect);

        selDiv = $("#selectedFiles"); 
        $("#myForm").on("submit", handleForm);

        $("body").on("click", ".selFile", removeFile);
    });

    function handleFileSelect(e) {
        var files = e.target.files;
        var filesArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(files);
        filesArr.forEach(function(f) {          

            if(!f.type.match("image.*")) {
                return;
            }
            storedFiles.push(f);

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var html = "<div><img src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" data-file='"+f.name+"' class='selFile' title='Click to remove'> <span class='selFile2'>" + f.name + "</span><br clear=\"left\"/></div>";
                selDiv.append(html);

            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(f); 
        });

    }

    function handleForm(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var data = new FormData();

        for(var i=0, len=storedFiles.length; i<len; i++) {
            data.append('files[]', storedFiles[i]);
        }

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', 'upload.php', true);

        xhr.onload = function(e) {
            if(this.status == 200) {
                console.log(e.currentTarget.responseText);  
                alert(e.currentTarget.responseText + ' items uploaded.');
            }
        }

        xhr.send(data);
    }

    function removeFile(e) {
        var file = $(this).data("file");
        for(var i=0;i<storedFiles.length;i++) {
            if(storedFiles[i].name === file) {
                storedFiles.splice(i,1);
                break;
            }
        }
        $(this).parent().remove();
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

..
 upload.php page

```
for($i=0;$i < count($_FILES["files"]["name"]);$i++)
    {
        if($_FILES["files"]["name"][$i] != "") 
        {       
            $tempFile = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];                     

            $targetFile =  "upload/". $_FILES["files"]["name"][$i];  

            move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);      
        }
    }
```

Comment: var file = $($this).data("file");  Please remove $this and write $(this).

Comment: It still not work with other selector

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668314/form-submitted-multiple-times-when-using-the-submit-callback-and-ajax-to-pos . This can help you.  As your form is getting submitted twice.